# Get derivativeId/mlid from the menu entity id in drupal

Tags: drupal, wp-mega-menu

I have menu entity id (menu id) for specific menu items in drupal. I have 3 level megamenu for that I am using we-megamnu dupal module. I want to alter the content of the 3rd level menus by matching menu id in the hook. But I dont know how to match menu id and derivative id.

Is there weay to match or convert menuid with derivative id or converting menu entity id to derivative id and vice versa?